# ¿Cómo modifico este método para todo el sitio?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo este método que en un principio era para un par de páginas, pero ahora resulté usándolo en casi todas las páginas `.aspx` del sitio.
Lo que hace este método es devolverme como variables los datos de la tabla Users y ya luego uso las variables según lo que vaya necesitando por ejemplo:

```
if (app_Area = 1)
{// direcciona al area 1}
else 
{// direcciona al area de registro nuevo usuario}
```

Mi pregunta es; ¿cómo hago para crear esto solo una vez y luego hacer el llamado a las variables que contiene sin tener que copiar y pegar en cada pagina.aspx.cs?

Código:

```
    protected void getData_Var(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Session["Username"] = User.Identity.Name;
                int app_Permissions, app_Area;
                string app_Token;
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT app_Permisos, app_Area, app_Token FROM Aplicativos WHERE app_Nombre='Landing'", con);
                    System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                    app_Permissions = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["app_Permisos"]);
                    app_Area = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["app_Area"]);
                    app_Token = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["app_Token"]);
                }

        }
```

Comment: una clase? variables de sesion? creo que hay varias opciones.

Comment: Me suena más la de clase, porque la variable de sesión no se como sería, y clase pues tampoco (aunque entiendo un poco más), traté creando una clase pero no entendí que o como se hace, se debe hacer ni mucho menos como usarla luego y me arrojaba solo errores y me petó el sitio de pruebas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoca este metodo una sola vez. Y los datos que devuela este, guardalos en una variables de Session.

Despues vas a poder acceder a esa variable desde cualquier parte de tu proyecto.

**Ejemplo guardar datos:**

```
 Session["appArea"] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["app_Area"]);
```

**Ejemplo sacar datos:**

```
 int appArea= (int)Session["appArea"];
```

Comment: Ya veo por donde va tu idea y pues suena bien, logré comprender el concepto pero me está arrojando errores constantes porque  creo que se pierde la variable, tendría que organizar bien en donde cargo esa variable y cómo evitar el error de Objeto no establecido. Creo que así cómo me comentas me puede servir y no tendría que realizar la consulta a la DB cada que cambia de página cierto?

Comment: _no tendría que realizar la consulta a la DB cada que cambia de página_
exacto, el contenido de esas variables duran hasta que no las destruyas