# Variable de session: Error: Referencia a objeto no establecida como(...)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Buenas! en una pregunta anterior quería saber como mantener una variable para todo el sitio y poderla usar cuando la necesitara: [Pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111597/c%C3%B3mo-modifico-este-m%C3%A9todo-para-todo-el-sitio)

Pero ahora estoy obteniendo este error muy seguido...
[image: Error captura]

Probé con esto y no funciona, entre otras muchas pruebas que hice como agregar:

```
//prueba 1
      if (per_App0 == 0 || per_App0 == null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        }
// prueba 2
    per_App0 = new (int)Session["per_App0"];
//prueba 3
    new per_App0 =  (int)Session["per_App0"];
```

Este error no aparece inmediatamente se carga la página, si inicio sesión y voy a la página funciona normal, pero al cabo de un tiempo X cuando refresco la página aparece el error, así que supongo que es como si se estuviera finalizando la sesión, pero si le doy atrás y vuelvo a ir a otra página me doy cuenta que la sesión sigue activa pues no pide contraseña ni devuelve al login.

Comment: ¿Hay algun lugar donde pongas valor a Sesion["per_App0"]?  porque si no le pones este valor en ningun lugar antes de consultarlo te va a fallar siempre.

Comment: Esto te puede ayudar a entender este tipo de problemas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%c3%a9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%c3%b3mo-solucionarla

Comment: Si Veelicus desde la MasterPage, declaro la variable  `int per_App0 = (int)Session["per_App0"];`. Voy a revisar Gua-naiko-che, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta convertiendo el objeto en `Nullable<int>`, en vez de `int` solamente:

```
  int? per_App0 = (int?)Session["per_App0"];
```

`Session["per_App0"]` retorna null si no tiene objeto asignado en ese indice y como el tipo de dato `int` no acepta null, te lanza el `NullReferenceException`. Conviertiendola a nullable, le indicamos que puede aceptar null, encaso de que no haya ningun numero.

Tambien es bueno notar que un `int` nunca sera igual a null a menos que sea declarado como nulllable:

```
// per_App0 nunca sera null, asi que es innecesario hacer la comparacion
if (per_App0 == 0 || per_App0 == null)
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}
```

Ahora bien, si `per_App0` fuera `Nullable<int>` si es valido entonces comprobar por es igual a null:

```
int? per_App0 = (int?)Session["per_App0"];
if (per_App0 == null || per_App0 == 0)
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}
```

Nota: `Nullable<int>` y `int?` es lo mismo.

Comment: pues muy buena tu explicación y al agregar int? funcionó correctamente, aunque se me desapareció la variable, ahora debo buscar como recuperarla de nuevo, pero el error se fue, ya es cosa de mirar detallitos. Muchas Gracias!